# My ethernet IP cam is not getting an IP

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a dahua IP cam with Power over Ethernet connection to my router via a four port POE switch.

It was working fine.  But I got an NVR and plugged it into it to test the NVR. Then I came back and plugged it back into the switch and found i'd lost it.

Can't access it from a browser.  Can't make it show up anywhere.  Like Contacam and Blue Iris.

It shows on the router as device with no IP.   At least I'm pretty sure that is it.

I had thought the IP in the camera was permanent. Apparently not.

I need an IP for it to connect to it, don't I - there's no other way?

How can I fix all this?

Comment: I suspect the IP changed.  It’s assigned by the router via DHCP.

Comment: Does it not support Zeroconf?

Comment: Have you tried using Angry IP Scanner or Advanced IP Scanner and scan your subnet to see if the camera is there with a new IP address? You should be able to determine your camera's MAC address (should be on the camera) and just find that with one of the tools I mentioned. Should only take minutes. It would be even easier if you could look at the DHCP client list in your router, the MAC address should be listed there with it's assigned IP address.